# $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ $\iff$ for all open $U\subset Y$ such that $f(x)\in U$, $f^{-1}(U)\in X$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> $f:X\to Y$, where $(X,d_x),(Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces, is continuous at $x\in X$ $\iff$ for all open(or closed) $U\subset Y$ such that $f(x)\in U$, $f^{-1}(U)\in X$ is open(or closed).

This question is very similar to a more popular question, but under the current requirements I am quite clueless:

Suppose I took an arbitrary $y\in f^{-1}(U)$, how could I guarantee the existence of an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{d_{X}}(y,\varepsilon)\subset f^{-1}(U)$ where my only area of area of certainty is a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$, seeming to provide no further information about any random $y\in f^{-1}(U)$.

**What I wanted to know** is whether or not the question as I understood it is solvable, and if it is, what I should be looking at. Hints and guidelines with respect to Topological terms are welcome.

Comment: You should come up with a more concise title.

Comment: I haven't arrived at a phrasing that stresses  the uniqueness of this question compared to other similar question, as I didn't want it flagged right away as a duplicate or answered irrespectively.

Comment: Your title doesn't say anything in particular that is different from the others, so you might as well choose something like "Equivalence of continuous function and open (closed) sets". And as for being flagged, that is up to the community to decide.

Comment: I really don't get it. Are you suggesting that the question above is very popular or that saying that continuity at $x\in X$ in that question is unequivocally continuity in all $X$ or all open sets? I don't really understand what is the bottom line of what you are saying. I do sense there is one, but I am afraid it is concealed by an articulate wording indirectly reproaching me for not comprehending.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is continuous and let $U \subseteq Y$ be an open subset. For every $a\in f^{-1}(U)$ we have that $f(a) \in U$, by definition. Since $U$ is open **there exists** $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B (a,\varepsilon) \subseteq U$. Since $f$ is continuous, for this $\varepsilon$, *there exists* $\delta > 0$ such that $$f(B (a,\delta)) \subseteq B(f(a),\varepsilon) \subset U$$ Therefore $B(a,\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Showing that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.